# Post request with basic auth in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Using Retrofit I post my contact list on the phone without authentication. I need to do retrofit basic authentication, but as far as I can't see from the internet. Can you help me, please?

This is my Code:

```
public void GetContactsIntoArrayList(){

    mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
    final User user = new User();
    final Post post = new Post();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int i = 0;
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        phonenumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        StoreContacts.add(name + " "  + ":" + " " + phonenumber);
        user.setphoneNumber(phonenumber.toString().trim());
        user.setname(name.toString().trim());
        List<User> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneList.add(user);
        post.setUsers(phoneList);
        sendPost(post);
    }

    cursor.close();

}

public void sendPost(Post post){
    mAPIService.savePost(post).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            Log.d("requestError", "onResponse: "+ call.request().body().toString());
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i("Is Ok?","OK :)");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so far the easiest method i have ever tried for "Basic Authentication".

Use the below code to generate the auth header (API/Repository class)

```
 var basic = Credentials.basic("YOUR_USERNAME", "YOUR_PASSWORD")
```

Pass this as header to the webservice call (API/Repository class)

```
 var retrofitCall = myWebservice.getNewsFeed(basic)
```

Add the basic header as parameter (Retrofit Webservice interface class)

```
 @GET("newsfeed/daily")
 fun getNewsFeed(@Header("Authorization") h1:String):Call<NewsFeedResponse>
```

My code is in Kotlin, just in case you were looking for Java. But can be easily translated to Java.

References: https://mobikul.com/basic-authentication-retrofit-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can add auth value in header of the request like if you want to send auth token then follow below step:

```
@POST("/auth/update-contactno")
    @Headers(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        Constants.headerApp,
        Constants.headerLanguage,
        Constants.headerPlatform,
        Constants.headerVersion
    )
    fun updateMobileNumber(@Header(Constants.authorization) token: String?, @Body verifyForgotPasswordOTPInput: VerifyForgotPasswordOTPInput): Call<JsonObjectResponse<UserModel>>
```

And call `updateMobileNumber()` like :

```
apiService.updateMobileNumber(token, verifyForgotPasswordOTPInput)
```